# Strategy for finding which of the 2 coins is more biased based on tossing a total of 100 times

Tags: probability

There are two variants of this problem that I want to solve. (1) One coin is fair. Other is biased towards heads. (2) Both coins are biased towards heads.

You have 100 tosses. What is your strategy to determine which coin is biased in (1), and which coin is more biased than the other in (2)?

For (1), the most obvious solution that I can think of is toss a single coin 100 times. If the number of heads and tails comes out to be about even, then we conclude that the other coin is the biased coin. For (2), we toss each coin 50 times, and claim that the coin that resulted in the higher proportion of heads is the more biased coin. Is this correct?

This seems like a very simplistic way to think about the problem if this is the correct strategy.

I also don't think my strategy is foolproof. For example, what if the bias was small like for example the biased coin has a 51% of being heads in (1), then the confidence in my strategy isn't great.

Comment: Random flipping is not a good way to test bias unless the bias is large.  If the coin is fair, on 100 flips the expected standard deviation is $5.$  Any less than a 10 flip deviation and you can't reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: @DougM. Hmm good point. Are there any alternative approaches? Also, how would hypothesis testing work for the second case?

Answer (score 2):

If the difference in bias is small, only $100$ tosses may not be enough to tease it out.  For case $1$, it seems an adaptive strategy might be better.  The biased coin may be strongly biased and it will be obvious.  Say you flip both coins $10$ times.  If one comes up heads all $10$ times, it would seem better to keep flipping that one.  If the probability of heads is $p$, the standard deviation of the number of heads in $n$ tosses is about $\sqrt {np(1-p)}$.  If $p$ is close to $1$, the standard deviation is small, and you are sure to be far from $\frac 12$ heads.  You will then identify the coins correctly.

Comment: What if $p$ of the biased coin was close to 0.5?

Comment: If it is very close, nothing will work.  That was the point of the first sentence.  If both sets of $10$ flips yield something close to $5$ heads, probably you should flip both coins a few more times.

Comment: If the difference in bias for both cases was large, what would be the issue with my approach (flip a single coin 100 times) for case (1) compared to yours?

Comment: If you get close to $50$ heads you would say you were flipping the unbiased coin, but have less certainty than if you flip the other one, say $10$ times, get lots of heads, and flip it the rest of the times.  The standard deviation of the number of heads decreases as the bias increases, so you buy more certainty by flipping the biased coin.

Comment: Makes sense. The CLT and Law of Large Numbers apply here right? Edit: I think the CLT would only be relevant if you were doing hypothesis testing and confidence intervals.